# Tengo que escribir una función que reciba un número entero y un dígito válido que cuente el número de veces que aparece el dígito en el número

Tags: python

Deberia verse asi:

> > > (17087, 7)
> > > 2

Quiere decir, que el 7 aparace 2 veces en el numero

Comment: Estás en SO en Español, traduce tu pregunta con el código y un ejemplo mínimo verificable.

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para aprovechar las funciones ya definidas por Python y no reinventar la rueda creo que lo más sencillo es utilizar la función [count()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_count.asp) de la clase Str de Python.
Dicha función requiere un parámetro de tipo Str, que es la cadena o carácter a buscar. Además el método definido abajo pide un segundo parámetro (c) que es la cadena a buscar.

```
def cuentanumeros(n, c):
    """
    Función que cuenta la aparición de un carácter o String en un String dado. 
    Para que la función sirva para buscar enteros lo que se hace es 
    un casteo a Str() de ambos parámetros.
    :param n: String en el que se va a buscar
    :param c: String que se va a buscar
    :return: Número de ocurrencias
    """
    return str(n).count(str(c))
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: Tenéis toda la razón, las cosas bien explicadas son más fáciles de entender. Antes respondí con prisa y me disculpo por ello. Gracias por vuestros apuntes, es un placer tener un hueco en esta comunidad y poder ayudar a otros :)